# Laravel 5.1 Download PDF with Event

Tags: php, events, pdf, laravel-5.1

My initial controller code for Event is:

```
try {
            $sales = $this->sales->create([
                'customer_id'       =>  $customer->id,
                'sales_details' =>  json_encode($vData),
                'total_price'       =>  ((int)$data['q-rfh'] * (int)$data['p-rfh']) + ((int)$data['q-rfh-spro'] * (int)$data['p-rfh-spro']),
                'created_by'        =>  $user->username,
            ]);

            \Event::fire('print.invoice', $sales);

            return \Response::json([
                'type'      =>  'success',
                'message'   =>  'Success creating sales!',
            ]);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return \Response::json([
                'type'      =>  'danger',
                'message'   =>  $e->getMessage(),
            ]);
        }
```

I need to print the invoice using event because I need to return a response with ajax to let user know the sales has been successfully made.

The event code is as simple as this:

```
public function handle(SalesModel $sales) {
        if ($sales) {
            $data = [
                'sales' =>  $sales,
            ];

            $pdf = \PDF::loadView('invoice.sales', $data);
            return $pdf->download('inv_' . Carbon::now() . '.pdf');
        }
    }
```

EventServiceProvider already listens to it:

```
protected $listen = [
        'print.invoice' => [
            'App\Events\InvoiceEventHandler',
        ],
    ];
```

Everything works fine, except that the PDF is not downloaded. I'm using `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` for creating and downloading the PDF. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You can not not return ajax response and download pdf at the same request, just it is not possible. One request -> one response.

Comment: Maybe you can add `window.location.href` in your javascript file after success message delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I give you and idea. Create the pdf file and store it at your server temporally

```
// return an absolute url
$pdfFile = \PDF::create('inv_' . Carbon::now() . '.pdf');
```

Now in your json response add the pdf file url in order to download it once the response arrives at client:

```
return \Response::json([
    'type'      =>  'success',
    'message'   =>  'Success creating sales!',
    'pdf' => pdfFile
]);
```

From javascript, at `success()` method you can call the pdf in other request

Comment: That was my second approach, although in the end I still use event to create a single pdf and store the location of invoice to database, since creating the pdf does take some time, to prevent the same invoice being loaded at same time by other user, and using another $.get immediately to download the inv once the response success.